# Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRDatabase' when using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Xcode tells me that `FIRDatabase`is not an identifier.
My code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true // Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRDatabase'
        return true
    }
}
```

I am using:

Xcode 7.2.1,
Firebase 3.0.2,
OSX 10.10.5

Podfile content:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myapp' do
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '<= 4.0.0'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '<= 7.3.1'
pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Comment: what is your pod file content ?

Comment: Updated question with its' content.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add

```
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

to your pod file as explained here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Here you can find which pod includes which feature
[Pods and Features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app)

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming it would be all installed with `pod 'Firebase'`. So I need to install all other features one by one?

Comment: i edited the answer with the link of what pod includes what

Comment: You also have to do a `pod install` in your root dir where your Podfile is located to get it to work.

Answer (score 29):

What worked for me, in addition to adding `pod 'Firebase/Database'`, was (which is missing from the current docs):

```
import FirebaseDatabase
```

Tested with Xcode 7.3.1, CocoaPods 0.39.0 & 1.0.1 on macOS 10.11.5. To make sure you're doing this correctly, please make sure your Podfile.lock looks something like:

```
PODS:
  ...
  - FirebaseDatabase (3.0.1):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.2)
  ...
```

P.S. I ran into CocoaPods issues that forced me to delete the derived data folder, so try that as well.

Comment: This is giving me a "no such module 'FirebaseDatabase'" error

Comment: @luckyging3r can you please share your Podfile.lock?

Comment: my podfile contents are:

     `pod 'Firebase'`
     `pod 'Firebase/Database'`

Comment: Fixed it with a `pod install`

Comment: @luckyging3r awesome, glad it worked. I was testing CocoaPods v1.0.1 to make sure. If you don't mind, you can up vote the answer so others will see it as well.

Comment: Welp, can't believe they forgot to add this on the docs. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

New syntax for using FIRDatabase:

```
Database.database().reference()
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

1. Add `pod 'Firebase/Database'` to your pod file
2. pod install
3. Open XCode and Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

1. First Just make sure your pod file contains pod 'Firebase/Database'
2. Add those two lines to your code:

import Firebase

import FirebaseDatabase

Answer (score 0):

1. add `pod 'Firebase/Database'` to your pod file
2. run the pod update command from your project dir
3. import

   `*import Firebase

   import FirebaseDatabase*`
4. Initialize and Configure your Firebase

   `*var ref: DatabaseReference!

   ref = Database.database().reference()*`