# Failed to add Firebase Database.framework without Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, firebase, frameworks, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add firebase's Database.framework without Cocoapods, but have compilation error

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kFIRDefaultAppName", referenced from:
      +[FIRDatabase databaseForApp:] in FirebaseDatabase(FIRDatabase.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error

Does anyone know which framework I should add too? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from this question [Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRDatabase' when using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619721/use-of-unresolved-identifier-firdatabase-when-using-firebase) , I can see that FirebaseDatabase depends on FirebaseAnalytics. After add all FirebaseAnalytics framework into the project, everthing works as expected. Hope this helps others too